# Support schedule for Cassandra versions

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I wanted to know till when Cassandra 3.11.10 is supported.
Is there some place where this information is available for all currently supported versions of Cassandra?
https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html specifies the maintained until date only for the latest available versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Download the latest Apache Cassandra 3.11 release: Released on
> 2022-02-08 Maintained until 4.2.0 release (May-July 2023)

This section covers all 3.11.x releases.  3.11.10 should be good until mid 2023.